# Не получается ссылку с переменной написать в php

Tags: php, переменные, echo, ссылка

Нужна активная ссылка чтобы в ней было две переменные

echo " <a href="\https:///vk.com/wall".$Idowner."_".$Idpost." "" ;
Пишу один вариант ссылка не активна, второй вариант ссылка активна, но переменные не подставляются.Третий
вариант закрыв кавычки после href= на локалхост (текущее место ссылается)

Comment: `echo "<a href=\"https:///vk.com/wall".$Idowner."_".$Idpost."\" ></a>";`

Comment: `echo "<a href='https://vk.com/wall{$Idowner}_{$Idpost}'>Text</a>";` @InDevX наверное не надо столько много кавычек и слэшей)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не вижу разницы, я просто добавил 2 слэша.. Так-то и без фигурных скобок можно

Comment: @InDevX можно без скобок, но так хотя бы в коде они выделяются. Обратные слэши читать тяжко. Если можно без них - лучше без них. ИМХО

Comment: так работает, спасибо

Comment: @InDevX конкатенации еще и работают дольше чем подстановки

Comment: @teran ну это смешно) вы наносекунды различаете? з.ы. я не говорю что конкатенация это круто, нужно, и она лучше, просто в данном примере разница лишь в визуальном представлении строки кода, всего лишь